# Completely positive, orthogonaly preserving maps

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

First of all, here is the setting for my problem:

Definition: Let $A$ be a $C^*$-Algebra, $a,b\in A$. We say, a and b are orthogonal, if $ab=ba=a^*b=ab^*=0$.

Proposition: Let $A$ be a $C^*$-Algebra, $a,b\in A$. Equivalent: a and b are orthogonal iff 1.$a^*a, b^*b$ 2. $a^*a, bb^*$, 3.$aa^*, b^*b$ and 4. $aa^*, bb^*$ are orthogonal.

I have some questions about the proof of the following

claim: Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*-$algebras and $\phi:A\to B$ be a completely positive map. Equivalent:

(i) for all positive elements $a,b\in A$ such that a and b are orthogonal, are $\phi(a),\phi(b)$ orthogonal  in $B$.

(ii) for all $a,b\in A$ such that a and b are orthogonal, are $\phi(a),\phi(b)$ orthogonal  in $B$.

Proof:

(ii)=>(i) is trivially true.

(i)=>(ii): Let $a,b$ are arbitrary such that a and b are orthogonal. By the proposition above are 1.$a^*a, b^*b$ 2. $a^*a, bb^*$, 3.$aa^*, b^*b$ and 4.$aa^*, bb^*$ are orthogonal and therefore 1.$\phi(a^*a), \phi(b^*b)$ 2. $\phi(a^*a), \phi(bb^*)$, 3.$\phi(aa^*), \phi(b^*b)$ and 4.$\phi(aa^*), \phi(bb^*)$ are orthogonal, because the elements $a^*a$ and so on are postive. But since $\phi$ is completely positive, we have $0\le\phi(a^*)\phi(a)\le \phi(a^*a)$ for all $a\in A$ (similary for the other elements). Now, orthogonality is a hereditary property, $\phi(a^*)\phi(a)$ are orthogonal and so on. By proposition above $\phi(a),\phi(b)$ are orthogonal.

My questions are:
1) I only know the corollary of Stinespring's theorem "Let $A$ be a $C^*$a-legrba, $\phi:A\to B$ completely positive. It is $0\le \phi(a)^*\phi(a)\le \|\phi\|\phi(a^*a)$ for all $a\in A$," and I know the proof of it. But in the proof above it is $0\le\phi(a^*)\phi(a)\le \phi(a^*a)$ for all $a\in A$, which is a different statement. And I dont understand why $0\le\phi(a^*)\phi(a)\le \phi(a^*a)$ for all $a\in A$ is true.

2)Which is the cosidered hereditary $C^*$-subalgebra of B here?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can repeat the proof with $\phi/\|\phi\|$, which does satisfy the inequality. If the authors didn't mention that their were sloppy, but the argument still works.
2. What they mean by "hereditary" is that if $a,b$ are orthogonal and positive and  $a'\leq a$, $b'\leq b$, then $a'$ and $b'$ are orthogonal.

One way to see this last assertion is by representing $A$ faithfully in $B(H)$. From $ab=0$, we get $a^n b=0$ for all $n\geq 1$, so $p(a)b=0$ for all polynomials with $p(0)=0$, and by taking sot limits $f(a)b=0$ for all Borel functions $f$ on $\sigma(a)$. In particular $b$ is orthogonal to the range projection $p_a$ of $a$. By using the same idea on $b$, we get that $p_ap_b=0$. Then
$$
a'b'=a'p_ap_bb'=0.
$$
As were are assuming the elements are positive, there are no adjoints to deal with.

Comment: thank you very much.  for the second explanation I need time to understand it. Ok, so you get norm =1. But what is about the difference $\phi(a^*)$ instead of $\phi(a)^*$? Because it is $\phi(a)^*\phi(a)=(V^*\pi(a)V^*)^*V^*\pi(a)V...\le \|\phi\|\phi(a^*a)$ for all a in A, here is $\phi(a)=V^*\pi(a)V$ with $\pi$ and $V$ as in Stinespring's theorem. But I will try it with $\phi(a^*)\phi(a)$ if I'm back home.

Comment: Difference? $\phi (a)^*=\phi (a^*)$, since $\phi $ is positive.

Comment: hi. I want to understand this too. First of all great answer! I still have two questions, hope it is ok. 1. are the polynomials dense in the (bounded?) borel measurable functions regarding to strong operator topology? 2. What exactly is a range projection of a?

Comment: 1. Yes.For a normal operator  $a \in B (H) $, you have $$\{a\}''=\{f (a):\ f \text { is bounded Borel on }\sigma (a)\}. $$ 2. The range projection of $a $ is the orthogonal projection onto  $aH $.

Comment: ok, thank you, I understand!

Comment: I have a question, again. Which $f$ gives me $p_a$? First I thought, f has to be the characteristic function $\chi_{ \{0\} }$, but this gives me the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(a)$. Furthermore it is not clear, if $0\in\sigma(a)$. And why is $a'=a'p_a$?

Comment: You take $\chi_{(0,\|a\|}$. And $a'=a'p_a$ follows from $a'=a'p_{a'}$ and the fact that $a'\leq a$ implies $p_{a'}\leq p_a$ (if $a'$ has part of its range orthogonal to the range of $a$, then $a'\leq a$ is impossible).

Comment: @Martin Argerami,I am also confused about this equality$\phi(a^*)=\phi(a)^*$,$\phi$ is a c.p map,not a $*$ homomorphism.